# Array into an array of objects in Java

Tags: java, arrays, csv

I'm a beginner and need to convert an array which I have scanned from a `.csv`, into objects. I have an array which holds the data but I need to create objects with it's values.

Below is the format of the `.csv`:

> Item No.,Description,Price
>  1234,square,10
>  4321,circle,5

```
    String xfile = "****";
    String input;
    String inputArray[];

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(xfile)));
    input = scan.nextLine();

    while (scan.hasNextLine())
    {
        input = scan.nextLine();
        inputArray = input.split(",");

        System.out.println(inputArray[2]);
    }
```

Here is the code I have already, which reads into the `.csv` file and puts it into `inputArray[]`. I now need to convert `inputArray[]` into an array of objects "Item" which has its own class with a constructor with "descrtiption", "itemNo" and "price" and also getters and setters.

The `inputArray[]` print prints the entire list of things. I want to make each line of the `.csv` a object, so to be able to set the item no, description and price of the item.

Comment: so what's your problem? you do not know how to write a class? you do not know how to write a constructor? you do not know how to new an object? you do not know how to access the data in array? you do not know how to convert from string to number?

Comment: @AdrianShum don't know how I can make the array which i read from the .csv into an array of objects where each object has a itemNo, Description and price.

Comment: It is still too broad.  The questions I asked are precisely what you need to know/do.  Which of them you are unclear of?

Comment: If you can't even understand what I asked, please get a book, learn the basics first.

Comment: @AdrianShum Well ultimately i'm unsure of the logic and what i can and can't do, i have the list of .csv and want to be able to create objects with the information the .csv provides me with, so an object which carrys a itemNo, Description and Price.

Comment: Show us the constructor for your Item class.

Comment: you already have a loop to print out each line of the file.  What you need to do is, instead of printing each line, create a new Item object and put it in an Array/ a List.  That's extrememly straight-forward.  And, the only way to find out what you can do and can't do is by actually doing it!

Comment: @Jason Okay i've finally done it, after a while of looking i realized the price in the .csv file was a double which kept messing up the code so i had to change to a double. Was quite simple to do but when you're a beginner it's hard!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String xfile = "****";
String input;
String inputArray[];

List<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<Item>();  // to store the list of items

Scanner scan = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(xfile)));
input = scan.nextLine();

while (scan.hasNextLine())
{
    input = scan.nextLine();
    inputArray = input.split(",");

    System.out.println(inputArray[2]);

    // assuming your item number and price are ints
    itemList.add(new Item(inputArray[1], Integer.parseInt(inputArray[0]), Integer.parseInt(inputArray[2])));
}
```

Comment: This gives me an error which says i can't convert string to int?

Comment: That's why I said you may have to do some type conversion. I'll edit.

Answer (score 0):

How about having an `ArrayList` of `Items`

```
ArrayList<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<Item> ();

while (....

    Item item = new Item(inputArray[1], inputArray[0], inputArray[2])
    itemList.add (item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String xfile = "****";
String input;
String inputArray[];

Scanner scan = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(xfile)));
input = scan.nextLine();

while (scan.hasNextLine())
{
    input = scan.nextLine();
    inputArray = input.split(",");
    Item item = new Item();
    item.setPrice = inputArray[1];
    item.setShape = inputArray[2];
    item.setNo = inputArray[3];

    System.out.println(inputArray[2]);
}
```

It think you are better to use the constructor than setters. Like that:

```
Item item = new Item(inputArray[1],inputArray[2],inputArray[3]);
```

You can also give the whole array to the constructor and put the logic in it.
After that you can put the object in a array.
I hope this help! :)

Comment: I've tried this but it tells me i can't convert String to int?

Comment: so please be specific on your question: are you having problem in converting String to int?  StackOverflow is a site that aimed to provide specific answer for specific programming question, instead of an I-have-a-homework-and-do-it-for-me kind of site

Comment: Use Integer.parseInt()  -> intValue =  Integer.parseInt(numericStringValue);
I had a down vote because I don't precised that?